# Throw error expects data to be sorted when xAxis title ENDS with number within a name

Tags: highcharts

I've a chart (column/bar), based on a HTML table.
The first column of the table (xAxis label) is a text that might contain some number such as a year.
When the year is at position :

- Start ("2022 Portfolio"): it works !
- Ends ("Portfolio 2022"): it doesn't work (see jsfiddle)

This causes the error #15 : Highcharts expects data to be sorted.
But I don't want them to be sorted, my business wants a special order.

Workaround: [If I surround the portfolioName by a hyperlink](https://jsfiddle.net/v5m1s0w9/4/), the issue is gone (hide hyperlink by CSS) !

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v5m1s0w9/3/) is a fiddle.

How can I achieve my goal ?
Remove the number or surround by `<a>` tag the first `<td>` and you will see the graphic will render properly (portfolio name with right width).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `type` for x-axis. Otherwise, Highcharts based on your data format ('Aux 2022') will set the type as `datetime`.

```
  xAxis: {
    ...,
    type: 'category'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bny83k2w/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: Many thanks ! Works like a charm. That makes totally sense.